# Combining results from multiple chi squared tests

Tags: r

I have ran 3 chi suqared tests and I have combined them using the code below.

df2 <- data.frame(chisq.test_age, chisq.test_eth, chisq.test_reg, chisq.test_sex)

I have attached a photo below of what happens. Is there a way I can have this so the results are not just in a straight line? i.e where I have the variables on the y axis and the results (e.g p value) on the x axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use broom's `tidy` and dplyr's `bind_rows`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

chit1 <- chisq.test(xtabs(Freq ~ Sex + Class, data = as.data.frame(Titanic)))
chit2 <- chisq.test(xtabs(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = as.data.frame(mtcars)))

bind_rows(
  tidy(chit1),
  tidy(chit2)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   statistic  p.value parameter method                    
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <int> <chr>                     
#> 1      350. 1.56e-75         3 Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 2    13222. 0              546 Pearson's Chi-squared test
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way. The tests' results are put in a list with `mget/ls`, then a series of `lapply` loops gets the relevant list members. Finally, `do.call` bind them together.

The tests are taken from [`help("chisq.test")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html).

```r
# 1st test
M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                    party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))
chisq.test_Xsq1 <- chisq.test(M)

# 2nd test
x <- matrix(c(12, 5, 7, 7), ncol = 2)
chisq.test_Xsq2 <- chisq.test(x)

# 3rd test
x <- c(A = 20, B = 15, C = 25)
chisq.test_Xsq3 <- chisq.test(x)

test_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^chisq.test_"))

test_list <- lapply(test_list, unclass)
test_list <- lapply(test_list, `[`, 1:3)
do.call(rbind, test_list)
#>                 statistic parameter p.value     
#> chisq.test_Xsq1 30.07015  2         2.953589e-07
#> chisq.test_Xsq2 0.6411203 1         0.4233054   
#> chisq.test_Xsq3 2.5       2         0.2865048
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>